# how do I delete an add-on in 2.79?

Tags: add-on

I installed an add-on, it didn't show up so I restarted Blender. It still didn't show up so I thought I'd load it again (I didn't check to see if it was in the add-on list). What happened is shown in the attached image.
[image: Screen Shot of Preferences]

Answer (score 1):

Try going to both of the directories and just remove the files completely. Then try installing it again to the Blender Foundation directory, checking every time if the add-on is visible in the list.

Edit: as batFINGER said, deleting the Users...\measureit folder would also suffice presuming that is you main blender directory.

Comment: Removing the `Users/..../measureit` folder  would suffice.

Comment: True, but it it confusing how they got the add-on to two different blender directories.

Comment: No it isn't.  Addons bundled with blender are in `[version]/scripts/addons` folder  of the  folder containing blender executable.  Addons installed manually by users in the Users folder.

Comment: Thank you, I feel stupid that I hadn't thought to go to the Blender directory. Thank you for your responses and for taking the time for me. Cheers